# C# Parallel_For stochastic?

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I tried using Parallel_For to make a computation in our program faster. Indeed, it is faster, but it seems to exhibit stochastic behavior: when I run it several times, I get slightly different results. Is this normal for Parallel_For?

Comment: Say parallel for decides you can have 5 active things at a time.. it can be sligtly different the order items run and finish.. but all will be done.. so it depends what you mean by different results

Comment: Yes this is normal, because parallel executes multiple instructions parallel and it depends on the state of your processorcores which thread will finish first. If you want to know more about this, you should read up on scheduling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)).

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "slightly different results".

Comment: putting in example code of what you are trying to do wil be very helpful...!

Comment: If you're getting different answers, then presumably at least one of them is incorrect. In that case, you likely have a race condition and you need to add some synchronisation. If you post some code, we might be more help...

Comment: When the end result is not the same after parallelization you haven't parallelized it correctly. You may have some data races or other race conditions in it. You cannot carelessly parallelize every loop you see, this *will* change the end result if you're not careful. You need locks (=mutexes/semaphores) when you do parallel programming for syncing. Without code, this question cannot be answered.